# How can I call a specific target from my makefile?

Tags: makefile

```
a:
   @echo 1

b:
   @echo 2

c:
   @if [ ! -d  somefolder ]; \
   then \
 # how do I invoke target b here?
   fi;
```

How can I invoke target `b` inside target `c`, based on my condition? Sort of like an `antcall`, if you're familiar with ant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just say `make b`