# calling another target inside my makefile without depending on it

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I would prefer to avoid a recursive call of `make`. Unless someone recommends this, it seems inefficient. (if someone does recommend it, we can mark as duplicate of [How can I call a specific target from my makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988688/how-can-i-call-a-specific-target-from-my-makefile))

I've found related threads but most of the solutions involve refactoring the make command, e.g.
[makefile execute another target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267145/makefile-execute-another-target)

or depending on the target that you want to run, e.g.
[How do I make a target in a makefile invoke another target in the makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337727/how-do-i-make-a-target-in-a-makefile-invoke-another-target-in-the-makefile)

In fact, I would be interested in how to refactor my makefile. I am newbie with makefiles so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm making things more complicated than they need to be.

```
# depend on all files in folder abc
myTarget1: $(shell find abc -type f)
  make otherTarget
  some commands...

# I have various targets that need to do the following:
.PHONY : otherTarget
otherTarget:
  common commands...
```

Comment: You have a number of make targets which all have the same shell commands that need to be run as part of their body?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes. I also run the target by itself.

Comment: That sounds like something that should be in a shell script that you can then call from the various targets and have a target to call manually to me. Barring that then a make `define` sounds like what you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you Etan, I will think about this possibilities.

Comment: The direct answer to the question is no, there is no way to invoke a specific target from within the recipe of another target except by invoking make recursively.